# Time complexity of this algorithm with two pointer - while within a for loop

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am struggling to find the time complexity of this algorithm. This is the code:

```
int sumClosest(std::vector<int> vec,const int& target)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    int diff = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for(int i=0 ;i<vec.size();i++)
    {
        int left = i+1;
        int right = vec.size()-1;
        while(left<right)
        {
            int sum = vec[i] + vec[left] + vec[right];
           
            //calculate difference from the target
            int sumdiff = std::abs(sum-target); //No need to check which is bigger. target or sum. So use std::abs
            
            //if there is no difference
            if(sum == target){
                return sum;
            }

            //Check if the new diff is less than what we already have stored
            if(sumdiff < diff) 
            {
                std::cout << vec[i] << vec[left] << vec[right] << std::endl;
                diff = sum;
            }

            if(sum > target)
            {
                right--;
            }
            
            else if(sum < target) 
            {
                left++;
            }
        }
    }
    return diff+target;
}
```

The above code uses the two pointer trick.
From my understanding:

1. Sort takes O(log)
2. The outer `for` loop, and then an inner `while` loop would be O(∙), so overall it will be O(log) + O(∙)

However, the explanation I was given is this:

> Here's the time complexity analysis:
>
> Sorting the vector using `std::sort` takes O(N * log(N)) time, where N is the size of the input vector `vec`.
>
> The code then uses a nested loop structure. The outer loop runs for each element in the sorted vector, which is O(N) iterations. The inner while loop runs in a way that it covers the entire vector once, making it O(N) iterations as well.  Inside the inner loop, there are constant-time operations involving addition, subtraction, and comparison.
> The dominant factor in terms of time complexity is the sorting step, which is O(N * log(N)).
>
> So, the overall time complexity of this algorithm is O(N * log(N)) due to the sorting step.  The rest of the algorithm, which involves searching for the closest sum, has a lower time complexity contribution compared to the sorting.

I do not think the above is correct. The `while` loop inside the `for` loop is O(), so combined `for`+`while` will be O(∙), and so overall it should be O(log) + O(∙) = O(²).

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: Seems like a O(n log n)

Comment: @VictorGubin can you explain.

Comment: Looks like O(n*n) to me. The dominant factor is _not_ the sorting step. As `n` increases, the `log(n)` becomes insignificant.

Comment: It's `O(n^2)`. The explanation would only have made sense if some kind of progress made during one iteration of the outer loop carried over to the next. But that's not the case. The inner loop always makes exactly `n-i-C` iterations (where `C` is some small constant; I'm too lazy to count my fenceposts, and it doesn't affect big-O), since `right-left` is reduced by exactly 1 on each iteration. Then `sum(n-i-C) == O(n^2)`

Comment: The given explanation doesn't make sense... `The outer loop runs for each element in the sorted vector, which is O(N) iterations. The inner while loop runs in a way that it covers the entire vector once, making it O(N) iterations as well` So That's `O(N^2)` and I don't get why the explanation jumps to sorting is dominant. Unless inner loop left and right are carried over for each inner loop but they're not. One possible chance is that the posted snippet is not related to the explanation.

Comment: inner loop body can run at maximum (exactly?) N times in total, to make left and right meet (if/else-if at teh end brings them 1 closer)

Comment: @James Franco your alg is close to merge sort, you are splinting area to reduce amount of searching. I think you already add the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is wrong. This algorithm is O(n^2) -- its worst case is O(n^2).

It's not complicated: the outer loop is O(n); the inner loop runs until `left` is greater than or equal to `right` but the range between `left` and `right` always gets smaller by only one unit on each iteration so the while loop in its worst case runs O(n) times.

An O(n) loop nested within an O(n) loop is O(n^2).